# Tuples starting with index 1, why?

Tags: python, pandas

I was working normally when my tuples started with index 1, did something change in the language and I don't know?

[image]

Wasn't my exit supposed to be "MMA8" and "MMA20"?

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output for `itertuples`, the first position is `index`

```
[*df.tail(1).itertuples()]
Out[234]: [Pandas(Index=4, ......)]
```

Comment: Also it is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas-dataframe-itertuples)